# How to lock a binary image for manipulation in Windows RunTime

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-runtime

I already have some C# code which is able to take the individual pixels of an input bitmap image and manipulate them, but it utilises the `System.Drawing` Namespace which is not supported in Windows RT. Instead it seems that `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging` is utilised for a Windows Universal file, which does not seem to have the capability to lock a bitmap whilst it is manipulated. Do people know of an alternative that will work for a data stream from a `mediaCapture` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly on an `ImageSource`, but you can create a `WriteableBitmap` from the image and read from its `PixelBuffer` property to access the raw pixel data.

Comment: Good succinct answer, appreciate the quick response!